# WCF Service at UWP

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I have a WCF service that can't be consumed from an UWP, now this WCF service can be installed in my LAN instead the web, it means that URL service can change from one customer to another.

Now my question is

How can  i Do to configure each instance of my UWP to route to the local service ?

Both projects are c# projects, but can't find the way to route the app to the local service. There is no App.config or other similar in uwp.

Comment: Hi, really don't understand the term mDNS, and how can I  do it into UWP ?

Comment: Could you tell us your steps to create the WCF and connect the WCF service? Does your WCF service can connect in web or it only does not work in LAN?